# caterpillar belt in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone !

I am trying to build a model in Gazebo which has caterpillar tracks like in tanks. Can you please suggest me how to do that in Gazebo ? The tracks are somewhat similar to the picture in this link : http://www.irobot.com/gi/images/research/lightbox/473.jpg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205950/caterpillar-belt-in-gazebo/) by [akshay5059](https://answers.ros.org/users/21984/akshay5059/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking around quickly I have found this [tracksdriveplugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/863/tracksdriveplugin) which seems to be a Gazebo plugin for tracks like you want. A good keyword when searching is "non rigid body".

Here is a related post  [Simulating a track driven robot](http://answers.ros.org/question/10410/simulating-a-track-driven-robot/)

Not an exact solution, but at least some pointers.

---

Originally posted by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) with karma: 285 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0